# protocolos, pasar información desde otras vistas a una desde una acción

Tags: swift, swift3

tengo dos protocolos para generar items dentro de collectionsViews, y se encuentran en diferentes vistas, un protocolo se encuentra en donde tengo un botón y la acción, para abrir la vista y generar esos items...

el primer protocolo esta en "PrimerViewController":

```
  protocol CollectionViewProtocol {
  func nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects)
  }

  extension PrimerViewController: CollectionViewProtocol {
  func nuevoElemento(item: SampleObjects) {

    self.misObjetos.append(item)

    let ip = NSIndexPath(row: self.misObjectos.count - 1, section:0)
    self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([ip])

  }
```

y el otro protocolo se encuentra en "SegundoViewController":

```
  protocol SecondCollectionViewProtocol {

   func nuevoItem(item: SampleOtherObjects)
  }

  extension segundoViewController: SecondCollectionViewProtocol {

      func nuevoItem(item: SampleOtherObjects) {

      self.misOtrosObjetos.append(item)

      let ip = NSIndexPath(row: self.misOtrosObjectos.count - 1, section:0)
      self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([ip])

  }
```

y en la vista donde se agregan los items que es "ViewController"

ahi se encuentran los delegados para acceder a los datos de los protocolos:

```
    var collectionControllerProtocol: CollectionViewProtocol?
    var secondCollectionProtocol: SecondCollectionViewProtocol?
```

todo bien aqui, ahora en la función del botón para llamar la vista para agregar los items hago como me enseño amablemente @Spidvmp esa acción esta en "PrimerViewController" en donde se encuentra el primer protocolo:

```
  @objc func llamarVistaAddItems() {

    let viewController = ViewController()
    let segundoViewController = SegundoViewController()

    let addView = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)
    viewController.collectionViewProtocol = self 
    viewController.secondCollectionProtocol = segundoViewController 
    present(addTrackView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

usando el primer protocolo funciona bien, pero cuando coloco el segundo protocolo aqui dice que hay un error de desempaquetado, justo en la función del segundo protocolo:

```
   extension segundoViewController: SecondCollectionViewProtocol {

  func nuevoItem(item: SampleOtherObjects) {

  self.misOtrosObjetos.append(item)
```

> let ip = NSIndexPath(row: self.misOtrosObjectos.count - 1, section:0)
>         self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([ip])

me dice: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
  }
```

pense que al crear la referencia:

```
   let segundoView = SegundoViewController( )
```

se crea un nuevo SegundoViewController y esto genera uno distinto al que queremos enlazar... o quizá algo hice mal... gracias adelantadas 
y gracias a @Spidvmp que ha aportado y ayudado mucho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los protocolos te van a servir para conectar 2 controladores y lo que defines en él son los métodos que tiene que saber implementar el otro controlador. Incluso no tiene que ser controladores, pueden ser clases de objetos que hagan algo y que respondan. Un caso muy típico es un protocolo para conectar una modal con la vista que la llamó. Lo suyo seria declarar el protocolo en la modal y con una propiedad que sea del tipo del protocolo. Esa propiedad se la asignas al controlador que llama y es este controlador que ha de saber que hacer cuando la modal ejecuta ese método.
Supongamos la modal que tiene un UITextField y que devuelve lo que se ha escrito. Me voy a centrar solo en el protocolo. En esa modal tendremos un Action de un botón que se pulsará cuando se haya terminado de escribir y es este action el que ejecutara ese método.

```
protocolo modalProtocol {
    func termineDeEscribir(texto: String)
}
```

Declaramos un protocolo que ejecutara el método termineDeEscribir y pasará un String a alguien
En la modal, sabemos que tendrá que enviar a alguien lo que han escrito, y sabemos que vamos a utilizar ese protocolo, asi que en la modal necesitaremos una propiedad del tipo de ese protocolo, asi que podremos declarar en la modal

```
var modal: modalProtocol?
```

y además en la modal tendremos algo de este estilo

```
IBAction func click(sender: UIButton) {
     //han hecho click, le mando a quien este detrás de self.modal el método declarado
     self.modal?.termineDeEscribir(self.textField.text!)
     //cierro la modal
     self.dissmiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

De esta forma me dalo mismo quien ejecute esta modal, solo he de indicarle a la modal que su propiedad modal voy a ser yo y que ya me ocuparé de implementar el método del protocol, asi pues si ViewController quiere abrir la modal, tendré que indicarle que me pase a mi lo del protocolo. Por ejemplo, en ViewController:

```
@IBAction func abrirModal() {
    //creo la vista a mostrar
    let vc = VistaModal()
    //ahora le digo que su propiedad modal,, la del protocolo, que  me lo envie a mi
    vc.modal = self
    //muestro la modal
    self.present(vc, animated:true: completion:nil)
}
```

Llegados a este pundo Xcode te dirá que esta vista no implementa el protocolo, asi pues, vamos a implementarlo. Tiene que estar dentro del controlador, asi pues:

```
extensión ViewController: modalProtocol {
   func terminedeEscribir(texto: String) {
        //recibo lo que se pulso en la modal. Como estoy en ViewController
        //podría por ejemplo asignarlo a algún ítem de ViewController
        print(texto)
   }
}
```

Eso es todo. En tu caso, te estas liando con donde implementar el segundo protocolo. Si tu ViewController tiene que recibir la información de los 2 protocolos, pues tienes que hacer 2 extensión de tu ViewController, uno para el protocolo CollectionViewProtocol y otra extensión de ViewController para el protocolo SecondCollectionViewProtocol.
No pasa nada por tener 2 protocolo, o 3, o los que quieras sobre un controlador.

Comment: o sea que, me hace falta crear esas dos extensiones dentro del ViewController en donde se añaden los items? de lo de mas esta bien como esta entonces, y como tengo dos protocolos genera ese valor nulo, por que hace falta las extensiones de las funciones ese ViewController?

Comment: es ViewController quien va a atender los 2 protocolos, asi que si, tienes que ponerle los 2 protocolos a ViewController. La modal tiene un resultado y sabe que tiene que enviárselo a través del protocolo a quien sepa que hacer con ese valor. El viewController implementando el contenido de esa función sabe que hacer con el valor que le pasa la modal

Comment: muchas gracias @Spidvmp por tomar el tiempo y responder tanta pregunta, comienzo a comprender un poco eso de los protocolos y como soy nuevo (se nota a leguas) aun no me queda super claro, pero creo ya lo estoy captando, ahora, ya implemente los protocolos en el ViewController, una duda? es necesario tener las extensiones dentro de las clases primertviewcontroller y segundo?... ya que los estaría colocando en ViewController y los métodos pues los haría el ViewController, hice esto: extension ViewController: fistviewProtocol, secondViewProtocol { y aqui se implementan los metodos }

Comment: El extension es como decirle a una clase que esa parte también es de la clase. Lo bueno es que lo puedes escribir donde quieras. Yo tengo la costumbre de los delegados y protocolos hacerlo en una extension, así si algún día es muy largo lo puedo llevar a un fichero diferente y todos los métodos están en el mismo sitio. Por ejemplo seguramente tu harás class ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource y ahí dentro pones todo. Yo hago un extension de UITableViewDelegate y otro para UITableViewDataSource