# Paso de parametros de un viewController hijo a padre despues de hacer un dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Desde un controlador padre llamo a otro hijo `( popoverContent )` con `self.present`, el controlador hijo es una típica vista en forma de popup que al acabar cierro con un dismiss pero deseo pasar unos datos a la vista padre.

Llamada dentro del código del controlador padre:

```
self.present(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

Cierro la vista hija (`popoverContent`) con una acción de un botón

```
@IBAction func exitButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

> ¿Cómo puedo pasar un parámetro de tipo String, o Int, o diccionario a
>   la vista padre después de cerrar la vista hija con dismiss ?

Comment: podrías crear un protocolo, o un delegado para pasar esos datos, tal vez si muestras mas código te podríamos ayudar de mejor manera, saludos!

Comment: He creado un protocolo pero no me convence pues si hay otras vistas que la funcionalidad es la misma y tengo que hacer mas protocolos  lo veo muy trabajoso.

Comment: buscas algo mas simple por lo que veo... haber si esto te ayuda mira.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmbUqTnfhNo&t=1s

Comment: El ejemplo del video habla de como pasar parámetros de la vista padre a la hija, pero a mi me interesa alreves

Comment: puedes mostrar que has intentado? igual eso nos ayudaría a todos para darte una respuesta mas exacta para lo que necesitas

Comment: Al final lo he implementado como protocolo pero creía que había algo mas fácil. De todas maneras la información que me habéis aportado es de bastante utilidad para otros proyectos. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas logico seria hacer un protocolo, puedes mirar esto: [protocolos, pasar información desde otras vistas a una desde una acción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126436/protocolos-pasar-informaci%C3%B3n-desde-otras-vistas-a-una-desde-una-acci%C3%B3n/126457#126457)

Pero si lo que quieres es algo mas sencillo, y vas a pasar un par de variables, puedes aplicar el mismo concepto que un delegado. 
En popoverContent te creas un var que es del tipo del padre, creas el popoverContent, a esa variable le asignas el valor del padre, la muestras y antes de cerrarla, popoverContent tiene una referencia al padre, así que podría modificar la variable del padre que quisieras.

En el popoverContent:

```
var padre: ClaseQueMeLlama?
```

En padre, creas y asignas:

```
//init del popoverContent
let popoverContent = popoverContent(........)
popoverContent.padre = self
self.present(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

Para cuando vayas a cerrar el popover:

```
@IBAction func exitButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //aqui le pasas los valores que quieras al padre, que tendrán que estar definidos y ser public
    self.padre?.foo = self.foo
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Esta solución la veo bastante buena, pero no se podría hacer sin crear la var padre: Clase asignando desde la clase hija una variable con self.parentView.foo = self. foo o self.superview.foo = self.foo ?? o algo parecido ??

Comment: Esto la verdad que no lo he probado, pero la hija debería tener un ser.presentedViewController o self.presentingViewController que deberías hacerle un cast a ala vista padre y lo mismo funcionaria, pero esta solución es mas limpia y mas clara y el protocolo todavía mejor que esto

Comment: Con self.presentedViewController y self.presentingViewController y haciendo  Cast como dices me reconoce las variables publicas de la vista padre cuando escribo el código en la vista hija. Aunque no he tenido tiempo de compilar para ver si el valor se cambiaba en la vista padre. ¿ Que diferencia hay entre presentedView y presentingView ?¿ Para que se suele usar?

Comment: Otra prueba que he hecho ha sido crear en la clase hija una constante let instanciada con UIStoryboard y casteada con el controlador padre. Al usar esta constante reconoce también las variables publicas de la vista padre. Pero no he llegado a probar compilando si variando una de estas variables publicas cambia el valor.

Answer (score 1):

Pasar datos desde un ViewController hijo a uno padre puede ser realizado por un protocolo alojado en el padre y "manipulado" por el hijo pero considero que puede ser algo un tanto molesto implementar estas funciones.

Una forma en la que puedes manipular tus variables es:
1. Crear una clase en la cual almacenes los datos que necesitas.
2. Crear una variable estatica para acceder a dicha clase desde cualquier controlador sin necesidad de crear un nuevo objeto de esta misma clase.
3. Implementar set y get para poder acceder a tus datos.

Algo como esto:

```
class almacenamiento: NSObject
{
    static let sharedInstance = almacenamiento()
    var dato1: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public func set_value(nuevoValor: String)
    {
        self.dato1 = nuevoValor
    }

    public func get_value() -> String?
    {
        return self.dato1
    }
}
```

La manera en la que puedes recuperar la informacion es, por ejemplo desde el metodo viewWillAppear():

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        almacenamiento.sharedInstance.set_value(nuevoValor: "Hola mundo")
        if let value = almacenamiento.sharedInstance.get_value()
        {
            print("\nValor por medio de metodo get: \(value)")
        }

        if let value = almacenamiento.sharedInstance.dato1
        {
            print("Valor extraido directamente de la clase: \(value)\n")
        }
    }
```

Imprime:
Valor por medio de metodo get: Hola mundo
Valor extraido directamente de la clase: Hola mundo

Comment: La idea que propones no esta mal pensada crear una clase estática para que las variables puedan ser accedidas desde cualquier vista. Pero teniendo encuenta que es una vista padre que no desaparece sino que presenta otra vista a modo de Popup no hay otra manera mas sencilla ? Por ejemplo antes de hacer un dismiss de la vista hija, acceder a alguna variable de la vista padre con ParentView o SuperView ?

Comment: Si gustas tener una conexion mas directa entre los controladores puedes observar este tutorial en el que usan protocolos para retornar valores: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/pass-information-back-to-the-previous-view-controller/